# How to ignore a single double quotes when importing a csv file in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, mongoimport

I am trying to import a csv file to MongoDB in cmd using mongoimport.

Some of my csv fields contain a single `"double quotes"` like so:

```
Dave, 25, 406-836-3336, "51 Ashleigh St, 20141123
```

I would like them either to be ignored, or imported as empty string.
I don't care for the address field really. I don't care how it will be imported as no operations will be made on it.

All I really care is that all the rows will be imported.

Comment: clean up your csv before importing that's all I see

Comment: Yeah, actually it was very easy since it is only 4 csv files. I guess that is good enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace a `double-quote` with double `double-quote`

```
Dave, 25, 406-836-3336, ""51 Ashleigh St, 20141123
```

From `mongoimport` docs:

> The csv parser accepts that data that complies with RFC RFC 4180. As a result, backslashes are not a valid escape character. If you use double-quotes to enclose fields in the CSV data, you must escape internal double-quote marks by prepending another double-quote.

**replace with sed**

```
sed 's/"/""/' test.csv > test2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the research. Much appreciated!